# CakePHP form will not submit as Post method and returns no data

Tags: php, cakephp

I Am creating an authentication in Cake. I have the following code in register.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array('class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $this->Form->input('password_confirmation', array('type'=>'password', 'class' => 'form-control'));
                        echo $this->Recaptcha->show(array('theme' => 'white'));
                        echo $this->Recaptcha->error();
                        ?>
                        <p>
                        <?php
                              echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Register',  'class' =>"btn btn-lg btn-block ".  $this->Buttons->color($account['Config']['theme'])));
                        ?>
                    </p>
```

In my UsersController.php, I have:

```
  public function register() {
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your account has been registered. Please check your email.');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'account'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
            }
        }
             $this->set('title', 'Registration');
    }
```

Now when I submit the form, It appends the input fields to the end of the URL as a GET Method and no data is passed to the controller. Here is the rendered html code:

```
<form action="/users/register" id="UserRegisterForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input email required">
            <label for="UserEmail">Email</label>
            <input name="data[User][email]" class="form-control" maxlength="255" type="email" id="UserEmail" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="input text required">
            <label for="UserFirstName">First Name</label>
            <input name="data[User][first_name]" class="form-control" maxlength="100" type="text" id="UserFirstName" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="input text required">
            <label for="UserLastName">Last Name</label>
            <input name="data[User][last_name]" class="form-control" maxlength="100" type="text" id="UserLastName" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="input tel required">
            <label for="UserPhone">Phone</label>
            <input name="data[User][phone]" class="form-control" maxlength="20" type="tel" id="UserPhone" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="input password required">
            <label for="UserPassword">Password</label>
            <input name="data[User][password]" class="form-control" type="password" id="UserPassword" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="input password required">
            <label for="UserPasswordConfirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
            <input name="data[User][password_confirmation]" class="form-control" type="password" id="UserPasswordConfirmation" required="required" />
        </div>
        <script>
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
            "theme": "white"
        };
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcDOecSAAAAAPgyYLxxtad0urkh9f-AgJ1IYLDE"></script>

        <noscript>
            <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcDOecSAAAAAPgyYLxxtad0urkh9f-AgJ1IYLDE" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            <br/>
            <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
        </noscript>
        <p>
            <div class="submit">
                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning" type="submit" value="Register" />
            </div>
```

I cannot seem to find the problem. Maybe, someone here would know the answer.

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: `Now when I submit the form, It appends the input fields to the end of the URL` a common cause for that is a nested form tag. You can't have a form tag in a form tag; i.e. it's quite likely you're not submitting this form `<form action="/users/register"` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lay in the use of captcha. I do not know how this is implemented, but it might affect the form. Try and remove it and see if it helps.

Also, you should probably start the form in the same div, like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php
        // Start the form
        echo $this->Form->create('User');

        echo $this->Form->input('email', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class' => 'form-control'));
        echo $this->Form->input('password_confirmation', array('type'=>'password', 'class' => 'form-control'));
        echo $this->Recaptcha->show(array('theme' => 'white'));
        echo $this->Recaptcha->error();
        ?>

        <p>
            <?php
                // End the form
                echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Register',  'class' =>"btn btn-lg btn-block ".  $this->Buttons->color($account['Config']['theme'])));
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. I have tried all kinds of things, but to no avail.